# Boolean_val vs Boolean.TRUE(Boolean_val) when used in a conditional statement

Tags: java, autoboxing

In [java](/questions/tagged/java) (1.8+) is there a performance difference between the following 2 if statements.  My code has to make a lot of these types of calls in iteration.

```java
void test(final Boolean val) {
    if (val) {
        ...
    }
}
```

and

```java
void test(final Boolean val) {
    if (Boolean.TRUE.equals(val) {
        ...
    }
}
```

Will the JIT compiler optimize away the difference?  Is the unboxing more expensive than the `equals` method call?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The unboxing is equal to `val.booleanValue()`, so the JIT should be able to [inline](https://techblug.wordpress.com/2013/08/19/java-jit-compiler-inlining/) such method.

The `Boolean.TRUE.equals(val)` looks better is the sense of `null`-safety, because autoboxing on `null`-value will cause a `NullPointerException`.

See also:

- [When Short Methods Pay Off: JIT Inlining](https://dzone.com/articles/jit-inlining)
- [Java JIT compiler inlining](https://techblug.wordpress.com/2013/08/19/java-jit-compiler-inlining)
- [Source code for `Boolean` class](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk10/master/file/be620a591379/src/java.base/share/classes/java/lang/Boolean.java) in Java 10 in the [OpenJDK](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenJDK) project.

Comment: +1 for null-safety. This is what Josh Bloch mentioned as "Autoboxing surprise left jab" at his presentation. Autoboxing blur distinction between primitive and reference type, but reference type is still reference type.